# Symbol about not orthogonality in LaTeX

Tags: math-mode, symbols, relation-symbols

I found [this post](http://www.thestudentroom.co.uk/showthread.php?t=567867), which explains orthogonal and not orthogonal symbols.

I was able quickly to find the orthogonal symbols as `\perp`, `\upvdash` etc., but not able to find a top line which strikes the sign from the top left to bottom right. One idea is to combine to symbols e.g., use one of the aboves and add the line in top of it. However I don't know how to do it.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly, but if you want to negate `\perp`, just add `\not` before it, e.g., `\not\perp`. I hope it helps.

Comment: I fully agree with that answer: addiction to symbols is dangerous; and `\not\perp` doesn't seem very useful to me.

Comment: @egreg Why is addiction to symbols dangerous?

Comment: @N.N. I'll repeat what I said in chat. As a young aspiring mathematician I was fond of symbols and overused them; experience showed me that less symbols and more words may make the exposition clearer. In some papers one can find newly created symbols that are used only a couple of times: these are obvious signs of "symbol addiction". As another example, long descriptions of sets with `X={x\in U:...}` may almost always be improved by saying `the set $X$ consisting of elements $x\in U$ such that ...`

Comment: In writing, you'll probably be better off being clear and using words, not symbols.

Comment: One should be careful about making pronouncements as to whether to use (mostly) words rather than symbols, or vice versa: different readers respond differently to different modes. Using both words *and* symbols can help. (See, e.g., Knuth's Rule 11 in http://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/reviewing-papers/knuth_mathematical_writing.pdf.)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

To negate the `\perp` (perpendicular) symbol, one could use the command `\not\perp`. However, IMNSHO, this negated symbol doesn't look all that good:

[image]

If you load the `mathabx` package, you get the command `\notperp` which looks pretty good, as does now the output of `\not\perp`. The same effect can be achieved if you load either the `MnSymbol` package or the `fdsymbol` package and use the command `\notperp` (same name used by both packages). Notice, though, that even if you load the `MnSymbol` of the `fdsymbol` package, the output of `\not\perp` still looks pretty bad, i.e., as bad as if you hadn't loaded any extra package at all.

**Addendum**: Following a request by the OP, here's an MWE that shows how to load the `mathabx` package and generate the symbol using the package's `\notperp` macro, as well as with `\not\perp`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\begin{document}
$a \notperp b$, $c \not\perp d$
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Next, here's an MWE that shows the use of the `MnSymbol` package to generate these symbols:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\begin{document}
$a \nperp b$, $c \not\perp d$
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Finally, with the use of the `fdsymbol` package and its `\nperp` macro:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fdsymbol}
\begin{document}
$a \nperp b$, $c \not\perp d$
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Happy TeXing!

Comment: Cannot load mathabx;                                             LaTeX Error: Command `\corresponds' already defined. Show a simple example how you do it!

Comment: @user44967: The style used in your comment could easily be misunderstood to be a little harsh and demanding. You probably didn't mean it as such, but the imperative paired with the exclamation mark are a bit off-putting. Maybe a better way to phrase a request for clarification would be "Could you show a simple example of how to use your solution?".

Comment: SORRY! Could you show a simple example of how to use your solution? and ... THANKS for your help

Comment: @user44967: I trust that the two MWEs I've provided in the meantime meet your needs.

Answer (score 10):

You can add a `\not` in front of it:

```
a \not\perp b
```

This gives you a struck through orthogonal symbol.